# Can I use ordinary JavaScript in CoffeeScript file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to add some JavaScript code in my Ruby on Rails application. I have already created for me, some js.coffee files for each view in my assets. Since, I am not familiar with the CoffeeScript I just passe some ordinary JavaScript/jQuery line in the file, such as:

```
if ($('#cart').length == 1) { $('#cart').hide("blind", {direction: "vertical" }, 1000); }

$('#cart tr').not('.total_line').remove();
```

but the following error was thrown:

> Error: Parse error on line 1: Unexpected 'POST_IF'   (in
>   /home/gotqn/Aptana
>   Projects/depot/app/assets/javascripts/carts.js.coffee)

The source is pointed on

> Showing /home/gotqn/Aptana
>   Projects/depot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6
>   raised:

and in this file on line #6 I got:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I am new in Ruby on Rails, but what I suppose is happening is that I am not able to write simple JavaScript in the CoffeeScript. If this is true, can I only remove the .coffe extension and be sure that the Rails magic will work and load the file?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? But yes, JS != CS.

Comment: Did you consider at least [reading the docs](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded) for CoffeeScript?

Comment: Or try renaming the `.coffee` files to `.js`, that might disable the automatic processing.

Comment: I have try first copying the ordinary JavaScript - the selectors, but get the an error. I am even not sure that the issue is there, since I am new in rails.

Comment: @millimoose I have look trough the docs and the examples, and make a similar search in google, but only found some similar errors without much explanation.

Comment: @gotqn I'm reasonably certain Rails should let you just use `.js` files somehow. Of course I can't link to the docs for that because it's apparently underneath Rails to provide complete reference documentation. Your question should be really "How do I use plain Javascript files in Rails 3.1+?" if that's what you intend to do, instead of a confusing question about how to bypass the syntax of a language you don't want to use at all.

Comment: Just remove the `.coffee` extension. All of the “Rails magic” will continue to work.

Comment: @georgebrock thanks a lot man. I stared to worry, because when I started to learn rails I am facing a lot of new things - ruby, MVC, YAML,SCSS and know this coffescript.

Comment: @gotqn: You don't need to use SCSS either if you don't want to; you can use plain old CSS.

Comment: @georgebrock Yes, but I've found it easy for learn and useful. Anyway, could you just tell is it a common practice for Rails developer to use SCSS and coffeescript or it is in the end personal choice?

Comment: It is a matter of personal choice, but if you're going to work as a professional Rails developer you're not always around at the start of a project to make that choice so you end up using both.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the docs on [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/):

> Hopefully, you'll never need to use it, but if you ever need to intersperse snippets of JavaScript within your CoffeeScript, you can use backticks to pass it straight through.

So yes, you can use JavaScript in CoffeeScript - [just surround it in backticks](https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/syntax/embedding_javascript):

```
`function greet(name) {
return "Hello "+name;
}`

# Back to CoffeeScript
greet "Coffee"
# => "Hello Coffee"

hello = `function (name) {
return "Hello "+name
}`
hello "Coffee"
# => "Hello Coffee"
```

It's highly advisable that you just convert your code to CoffeeScript instead, though.

Comment: "It's highly advisable that you just convert your code to CoffeeScript instead, though." - or, you know, not use it at all.

Comment: @millimoose Or that. Seems like what the OP really wants is to not use CS, but this is the answer to the current form of his question.

Comment: Agreed with @redhotvengeance, not always do we want the burden of learning yet another language to get a job done.

Comment: I wish you put this link: I wish you could put this link: https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/syntax/embedding_javascript

Comment: The escape feature is useful for when you don't have time to clean up a snippet.